# FPS : Hands+Weapon Animation

Tags: unity, blender, first-person-shooter

I want to create multiplayer first person shooter . Now I want to create animation where the soldier is walking with rifle . 
[image]

I have separated hands from the body of the model and I have dropped hands and rifle in the camera , but when I move the camera hands don`t move with camera but the rifle does .  Hands are controlled by the bone . How can I make the walk animation + camera movement together?

Comment: What do you mean with "dropped hands and rifle in the camera"? If you have a complete character model, it would probably be the easiest way to attach the camera to the head of that model. This should give the wanted effect of everything moving together.

Comment: yes I can attach the camera to the head of the model but how to rotate hands with camera?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? You should rotate the whole model by mouse movement, at least for looking left and right.    For looking up and down you would need to rotate the upper part of the model, starting at the hip.

Comment: yes but how to rotate the upper part if it is fixed by the rig position?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do this in unity. But if you have an underlying skeleton you could just rotate around the hip-joint. I think it works like that in UnrealEngine.